# How do I change a concrete variable to an existentially quantified var in a hypothesis?

Tags: coq

Say I have a hypothesis like this:

```
FooProp a b
```

I want to change the hypothesis to this form:

```
exists a, FooProp a b
```

How can I do this?

I know I can do `assert (exists a, FooProp a b) by eauto` but I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't require me to explicitly write down the entire hypothesis; this is bad for automation and is just generally a headache when the hypothesis are nontrivial. Ideally I'd like to specify `intro_exists a in H1` or something; it really should be that simple.

**EDIT**: Why? Because I have a lemma like this:

```
Lemma find_instr_in: 
  forall c i,
   In i c <-> (exists z : Z, find_instr z c = Some i).
```

And a hypothesis like this:

```
H1: find_instr z c = Some i
```

And I'm trying to rewrite like this:

```
rewrite <- find_instr_in in H1
```

Which fails with the error `Found no subterm matching "exists z, ..." ...`. But if I `assert (exists z, find_instr z c = Some i) by eauto.` first the rewrite works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Ltac intro_exists' a H :=
  pattern a in H; apply ex_intro in H.

Tactic Notation "intro_exists" ident(a) "in" ident(H) := intro_exists' a H.

Section daryl.
  Variable A B : Type.
  Variable FooProp : A -> B -> Prop.

  Goal forall a b, FooProp a b -> False.
    intros.
    intro_exists a in H.
  Admitted.
End daryl.
```

The key to this is the `pattern` tactic, which finds occurrences of a term and abstracts them into a function applied to an argument. So `pattern a` converts the type of `H` from `FooProp a b` to `(fun x => FooProp x b) a`. After that, Coq can figure out what you mean when you apply `ex_intro`.

---

**Edit:**
All that being said, in your concrete case I would actually recommend a different approach, which is to not state your lemma like that. Instead it is convenient to split it into two lemmas, one for each direction. The forwards direction is just the same, but the backwards direction should be restated as follows

```
forall c i z, 
  find_instr z c = Some i -> In i c.
```

If you do this, then the rewrite will succeed without needing to introduce the existential.