# Coq tactic for applying a concrete hypothesis to an existential goal

Tags: coq, ltac

Consider the following example:

```
Theorem example: forall (P: nat->Prop), P (1+2+3) -> (exists x, P x).
Proof.
intros. 
apply H
```

The `apply H` fails with

```
Unable to unify "P (1 + 2 + 3)" with "exists x : nat, P x".
```

So I know that I could use the tactic `exists 1+2+3` to get apply to work here, or, based on [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402952/how-do-i-change-a-concrete-variable-to-an-existentially-quantified-var-in-a-hypo) there is a more convoluted way to use forward reasoning on `H` to get it into an existential form.

But I would expect there is some smart tactic that can instantiate existential variables when it's unifying, without having to be explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need forward reasoning, you just want an evar:

```
Theorem example: forall (P: nat->Prop), P (1+2+3) -> (exists x, P x).
Proof.
intros.
eexists.
apply H.
```

You're being explicit here about creating an existential variable, and Coq is using unification to instantiate it.

Comment: Thanks!  I also found that `eauto` works here by itself.

Comment: Oh right - eauto is the way to create the evars on-the-fly, as long as it can solve the goal.